# Select 2 and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the basic example of select2 but it does not work.

I included this on the head of my page:

```
        <!-- select -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
            });
        </script>
```

I set class name of my select to class = 'js-example-basic-single'

but nothing happend in the console it showed me Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js:2

Comment: You might need to include JQuery first.

Comment: Could do you please show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the JQuery library included within the website?
If not, you can find latest libraries here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery/

I prefer to use `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`, as shown in this example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the error but my select did not change. It does not show the search box

Comment: You might need to select it using:
`$(".js-example-basic-single")[0].select2();`

Comment: Note how I added `[0]` which specifies a certain element.

Comment: I added that but still getting this error jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'select2' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'select2' of undefined

Comment: What are you using `select2()` for? I did a Google Search, and people are using it with parameters. These are one of them which fixes the same issue for a different person: `placeholder :'select..'` as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953467/cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined-select2)  question.

Comment: the idea is that I want to replace the classical select with select2 so that I can have a search box. But that search box does not appear at all. What am I doing wrong ?